# pad out to 3 digits in files recursively in ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I have many folders that contain images with 2-digit file names, for example...

```
gallery/gal001/images/01.jpg
gallery/gal001/images/02.jpg
gallery/gal001/images/03.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal001/thumbnails/01.jpg
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/02.jpg
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/03.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal002/images/01.jpg
gallery/gal002/images/02.jpg
gallery/gal002/images/03.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal002/thumbnails/01.jpg
gallery/gal002/thumbnails/02.jpg
gallery/gal002/thumbnails/03.jpg
etc...
```

but then others will have 3-digit filenames...

```
gallery/gal100/images/001.jpg
gallery/gal100/images/002.jpg
gallery/gal100/images/003.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal100/thumbnails/001.jpg
gallery/gal100/thumbnails/002.jpg
gallery/gal100/thumbnails/003.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal500/images/001.jpg
gallery/gal500/images/002.jpg
gallery/gal500/images/003.jpg
etc...

gallery/gal500/thumbnails/001.jpg
gallery/gal500/thumbnails/002.jpg
gallery/gal500/thumbnails/003.jpg
etc...
```

I need to make them all the same, so I want to pad out the 2-digit ones to 3-digits, without touching the ones that already have 3 digits.

As they are within folders, I have to do this recursively.

I have CD'd into the gallery folder and I have tried the following after searching through various threads and googling, but none of these attempts have worked :

```
find . -type f 'for f in [0-9]*; do mv $f `printf %03d ${f#}`; done'
```

```
for ((i=1; i<=N; i++)) ; do mv $i `printf %03d $i` ; done
```

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -print0|xargs -0 rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e'
```

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+|[^0-9]+' '{ 
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ($i~/[0-9]/? "%03d":"%s"),$i; 
           print "" 
       }' .jpg
```

```
$s = sprintf('%03d', $digit);
```

I appologise if this has been asked before, but as you can see, I have searched beforehand.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match only those with *2-digit filenames*, and prepend their names with a zero.

```
find . -name '[0-9][0-9].jpg' -exec sh -c '
for fpath do
  echo mv "$fpath" "${fpath%/*}/0${fpath##*/}"
done' _ {} +
```

Drop `echo` if you're happy with the output.

With [p]rename, of course this'd be easier, but it's not available on my system.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked a treat! I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/[0-9][0-9]\.[^/]+$' -printf "'%h/%f' '%h/0%f'\\n" | xargs -n 2 mv
```

you can change `mv` to`echo` to verify before final renaming

Comment: I wanted to post `source <(find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg' -printf 'mv "%p" "%h/0%f" \n' )`, which is safer when there are spaces in the filename. This is not really a different answer (and `xargs` is better than `source`), so I won't post this as an alternative answer. Perhaps you want to add some quotes in your `printf`.